# Fit function to experimental data

Tags: math, regression, julia, curve-fitting

I have exponential function ( gauss distribution )

```
 f(time)=exp(-((time-A)^2)/B)
```

and i have a experimental data that forms matrix [time, value]. What i want to do is perform some kind of tuning of A and B parameters, that will give me best result, which is getting 1st function as close to experimental data plot. 
This is what i've accomplished by tuning manually in Julia, but i'm looking for an automated way.

[image: Comparison.jpg]

Regards

Mike

Comment: A Gaussian is symmetric about `A`.  Your data definitely isn't (and neither is your fitted function).  Is your fitted function `exp(f)`?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from the picture, but it appears that your data are the response to a step change in a forcing variable. Actually, two step changes: one at about t=1.4 when the temperature increases, and one at about t=1.6 when it decreases. After each step change, a model for the temperature will probably be a decaying exponential, increasing or decreasing to a steady-state level. Something like `temp(t) = B + (A - B)*exp(-(t - t_change)/c)` for `t >= t_change` where `A` is the starting temperature, `B` is the steady-state temperature, and `c` is a time scale. `A`, `B`, `c`, and maybe `t_change` are free parameters. You can use the method of least squares to find them.

The tricky part is determining `t_change` from observed data. (But if you already know `t_change`, just plug it in.) You might have to formulate some kind of nested optimization -- for each of many possible values of `t_change`, optimize the other parameters. Then choose `t_change` which gives the best fit for the other parameters.

See Seber and Wild, "Nonlinear Regression", for more about models defined in pieces like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Here's your original function:

```
y(t) = exp(-(t-A)^2/B)
```

Take the natural log of both sides:

```
ln(y) = -(t-A)^2/B = -(t^2-2*A*t+A^2)/B
```

Now you have a 2nd order polynomial that you can fit using least squares to obtain the values for A and B that minimize the sum of squared errors.

Now that I can see your function I'd ignore the values before the jump at `t = 1.4 seconds`.  Fit the values for `t >= 1.4 seconds` only.

Answer (score 0):

The Gaussian distribution is uniquely determined by two parameters, mean value of the distribution (in your case `A`) and variance `sigma` (related to your `B` by `2*sigma^2=B`).

So you can just compute mean and variance for your data and plug those in your Gaussian.

Comment: I don't this is applicable. OP doesn't have count or frequency data.

Comment: @RobertDodier OP has data, therefore he/she can compute mean and variance of it. What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe you can explain exactly how you think OP should go about computing mean and variance from his/her time and temperature data.

Comment: I see your point. Initially I understood that the OP was trying to obtain a PDF of the temperature values, but I am not sure anymore this is what the question is about. The question is not clear at all to me at this point, especially because the plot shown (as pointed out by Teepeemm) does not show any Gaussian at all. Without any clarification from the OP I would only be speculating.